# Core data save entity issue

Tags: ios, core-data

This might be a very primitive question. I have a list of states that belongs to different countries.

```
Data 1: state - xyz
        country - A

Data 2 : state - abc
         country - B

Data 3: state - ght
        country - A

Data 2 : state - ase
         country - B
```

In core data i have differnt entities for state and country. While saving how do i put all the states to their country object?

**EDIT :** Country state relation

[image]

Comment: You will need relationships declared so the data and model conform. You should show how you have setup your entities, otherwise it will be hard to help you.

Comment: Have you set up relationships in the entity model?

Comment: YES.. Country to state - cascade one to many relationship

Comment: @SharanyaKM You can put states to country object by `addState:` method (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors) in `NSManagedObject` subclass `Country`, if you have set the relation and created `NSManagedObject` subclass.

Comment: how do i put it to specific country objects ? Do i need to fetch all the states with a specific country and then set it to a particular country ? If yes, how do i do that ?

Comment: @SharanyaKM you can do this on the first time entering states. ie. add states to core data by this relation only. `CoreDataGeneratedAccessors` can be used for this. And you don't need separate entry to `State` entity since it is being done by the relation.

Comment: @SharanyaKM you probably want one country to many states?!

Comment: @Akhilrajtr - If i have states like i have shown , how do i set it or add it to a particular country ??

Comment: @SharanyaKM I've added a sample. Check it, hope that will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Data is Array of Dictionary,

```
for (NSDictionary *data in datas) {

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Country" inManagedObjectContext:[dbManager getCurrentContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", [data valueForKey:@"country"]];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray * fetchedObjects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if ([fetchedObjects count] > 0) {

        Country *country = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        //Using CoreDataGeneratedAccessors
        [country addStateObject:[data valueForKey:@"state"]];
    } else {

        Country *country = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Country" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        country.name = [data valueForKey:@"country"];
        ...

        if ([managedObjectContext save:&error])
        {
             //Using CoreDataGeneratedAccessors
             [country addStateObject:[data valueForKey:@"state"]];
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this may help you

Comment: This is not the exact solution but it gives me an approach.. Will try the approach.. Thanks

Comment: Took the approach.. than the solution. Thanks buddy

Comment: This is just a sample. Happy to know you got solution. Cheers.